# Remote logoff citrix xenappsession

Tags: citrix, xenapp

How to programmatically log off a citrix xen app session ( I do know the server  , uid, pwd ). C# what apis to use ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WTSLogoffSession for the remote case as well as the local case. However you will need to get a handle to the server using WTSOpenServer first (and close it afterwards using WTSCloseServer). Note these are not C# APIs, they are native. However you can use Platform Invoke to call them from C#.